# How to determine when one of the expressions is greater. Irrational inequality

Tags: calculus

[image]When do we have $ \sqrt[3]{a^3+0.01}-a < a -\sqrt[3]{a^3-0.01} $

and when $ \sqrt[3]{a^3+0.01}-a > a -\sqrt[3]{a^3-0.01} $

I tried to find if they are equal at some $a$ and then plug in numbers from given interval. I only found $a=0$ and don't know if there are other such numbers. Or is there a better and easier way of doing it?

The original question is to find $\delta>0$ such that $|x^3-a^3|<0.01$ whenever $|x-a|<\delta$, where $a$ is a real number.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are trying to find the largest $\delta$ with the required property, which will generally be a lot more difficult than constructing a significantly smaller $\delta$ for which it's just easier to prove the property. Take for example $\delta = \min (1, \frac{0.01}{3a^2+3a+1})$
$$
(a + \delta)^3 - a^3 = 3 a^2\delta + 3a\delta^2 + \delta^3 = \delta (3a^2 + 3a\delta + \delta^2) \leq \frac{0.01}{3a^2+3a+1} \cdot (3a^2 + 3a + 1) = 0.01
$$
Now this is just a hint which should show to what extent it can be easier to manipulate inequalities if we choose suitable values. A complete solution would need to consider different cases for $a$ (in the above it's assumed positive) and add other missing details that I did not include so far.